# Connection issue while connecting to HANA DB via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, hana

I am connecting HANA DB via ngdbc.jar. Connection is made properly but after running query 3-4 times connection to HANA DB is lost. When I restart my JAVA server again it works for 3-4 times. Can anyone help?[image: Check error description here]

Error Msg-

```
WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) SQL Error: -708, SQLState: 08006
 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Data receive failed [Connection reset].
 INFO  [com.ultimatix.controller.MetricsController] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) context setMonthFreezeDateorg.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
 ERROR [org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) JDBC rollback failed: com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc40.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection to database server lost; check server and network status [System error: Socket closed]
```

Comment: yup connections can expire, use a connection pool and a proper "sanity check" query.

Comment: how to do these @RC.

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html#pooled_connection

Comment: Please check updated question @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using Hibernate based on your log.

Can you elaborate a little bit on your stack?

As @RC said, you should consider connection pooling instead of opening direct connections if this is what you are doing in your "JAVA" server.

May be your are keeping the connection open for too long and it times out.

These are all guesses, until you can share any logs or sample code.

One more thing,  related to the ngjdbc driver only, there is a "reconnect" connection property which by default is set to false.

Regards

Comment: I am opening connection before execution of each query and closing it immediately in finally block after query is executed. session=this.sessionFactory.openSession(); and after execution session.flush();
   session.clear();
   session.close();

Comment: Hi, based on the name of the method, I'm guessing that you are updating a table in SAP HANA. However, you didn't say if you were committing your change before closing the flush, clear and commit.
Have you tried to run a series of select only statement?